# show a ring is closed under symmetric differences

Tags: real-analysis, ring-theory

I've started learning with the book Basic Real Analysis by Houshang H. Sohrab.  Only this year I've learned the concept of *closure*. I feel very insecure about my work on the exercises and I don't have anyone who I can show my work.  Please see the work I've done on this exercise and provide your critique so that I can correctly communicate ideas in math.

> Show that a ring $\mathcal{R}$ is closed under symmetric differences. In other words, $$A,B\in\mathcal{R}\implies A\mathrel{\triangle}B\in\mathcal{R}\;.$$
>
> **Response.** Since $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring then when $M\in\mathcal{R}$ and $N\in\mathcal{R}$ then $M-N\in\mathcal{R}$ and $M\cup N\in\mathcal{R}$ for some $M$ and $N$. So if $A\in\mathcal{R}$ and $B\in\mathcal{R}$, then $A-B\in\mathcal{R}$ and $A\cup B\in\mathcal{R}$. And since for $A\in\mathcal{R}$ and $B\in\mathcal{R}$, the sets $A$ and $B$ are independent from each other, then we also have that $B-A\in\mathcal{R}$ and $B\cup A\in\mathcal{R}$.
>
> Now let’s consider the union $(A-B)\cup(B-A)\in\mathcal{R}$. By the above note, both $A-B\in\mathcal{R}$ and $B-A\in\mathcal{R}$ and if $A-B$ is $C$ and $B-A$ is $D$ which are both in $\mathcal{R}$. Then the union of $C$ and $D$ is in $\mathcal{R}$.
>
> The union under consideration is the equivalent of $A\mathrel{\triangle}B$ so $A\mathrel{\triangle}B\in\mathcal{R}$.
>
> This shows the ring is closed under symmetric differences.

(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsMsG.png).)

Comment: I fixed a typo and added MathJax in the places where you’d used plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is basically correct, but it’s much too wordy, and there are a couple of places where it could be stated more clearly. Here’s a cleaned up version for comparison:

> Let $A,B\in\mathcal{R}$. Since $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring, we know that $A-B$ and $B-A$ are in $\mathcal{R}$. We also know that the union of any two members of $\mathcal{R}$ is in $\mathcal{R}$, so
>
> $$A\mathrel{\triangle}B=(A-B)\cup(B-A)\in\mathcal{R}\;,$$
>
> and $\mathcal{R}$ is indeed closed under symmetric difference.

That really is all that you need to say: it has enough ‘connective tissue’ to make the flow of logic clear, but no more than is needed.

(By the way, nowadays the set difference $A-B$ is more often written $A\setminus B$.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the part about "independence". We simply know that a ring of sets is closed under union and symmetric difference. So if $A \in \mathcal{R}$ and $B \in \mathcal{R}$, we know by closure under difference that $A - B \in \mathcal{R}$ and $B - A \in \mathcal{R}$. And therefore we know by closure under union that $(A - B) \cup (B - A) \in \mathcal{R}$. The set $(A - B) \cup (B - A)$ is by definition the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$.

In other words: Use the facts that you know *and only those*.